# Simple Query Help Using XRMToolbox

Tags: sql, dynamics-crm, fetchxml, xrmtoolbox

I am using XRMToolbox and its tool "Bulk Data Updater" with Microsoft Dynamics CRM. I need to update a boolean value of multiple accounts after searching for them by account number. I believe it requires some type of JOIN.

I believe I have constructed the proper query, but when I try to Bulk Update (see picture), the attribute of the boolean value I need is not listed in the dropdown menu.

When I run this query:

- I get the results needed
- I get the specific user_id values I need, and I get their status "approved" which is the boolean value I need to change, but I can not edit these values because "approved" attribute is not listed in the dropdown menu

---

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false" >
  <entity name="contact" >
    <attribute name="user_id" />
    <link-entity name="application" from="applicant" to="contactid" >
      <attribute name="approved" />
      <link-entity name="contact" from="contactid" to="applicant" >
        <filter type="or" >
          <condition attribute="user_id" operator="eq" value="0000021" />
          <condition attribute="user_id" operator="eq" value="0000055" />
        </filter>
      </link-entity>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

> [image: XRMToolbox Image]

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: @UncleRico were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to set fields on an account, you need to query accounts, but you query contacts.

Answer (score 0):

You already chose the XrmToolBox plugin to use for bulk update, but the query is not the expected one to update back the results - i.e., you mentioned `account` but the query only has `contact` and `application` entities joined. So obviously the query is not composed from the right direction.

If you want to update the `application` entity, build the query in FetchXML builder starting from `application` entity rather than from related `contact` side.

Or you can build the Advanced find query to use, (or download the fetchxml from there or even save that Adv.find query as CRM view to use in Bulk Data updater) you can simply export/bulk edit the records in Excel online to save back. You can select 250 records at once to Bulk edit wizard or to run Workflow to update.

Every single approach need the parent entity list from query to update the field. Start over.